# applying rule only once using in_array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I was wondering how to do the following as I have been going around without an answer. So I will try to simplify as much as I can.

I have set some values for an associative array

```
$vNArray ['Brandon']  = $item[3]; 
$vNArray['Smith']= $item[4]; 
$vNArray ['Johnson']= $item[5];
$vNArray ['Murphy']= $item[6];
$vNArray ['Lepsky']= $item[7];

foreach ($vNArray as $key => $value){

if(!empty($value)){
   $result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key</strong>"  .$value.   "</li>\n";
}
```

But now I want to target specific values within that array so here is another array:

```
$display_id=array('Brandon', 'Murphy');

foreach ($vNArray as $key => $value){
if(!empty($value)){
   //Looks into the display_id array and renders it differently
   if (in_array($key, $display_id)) {
   $data .= "\t\t<li id=\"".$vNArray['Brandon']."\">".$vNArray['Murphy']."</li>\n";

} else {
$result .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key</strong>$value</li>\n";
}
```

}

The result for the first condition is correct but repeated for both in_array values:

```
<li id="Brandon Value">Murphy Value</li>
<li id="Brandon Value">Murphy Value</li>
```

Below is correct:

```
<li><strong>Smith</strong> Value of Smith</li>
<li><strong>Smith</strong> Value of Johnson</li>
<li><strong>Lepsky</strong> Value of Lepsky</li>
```

How do I stop it from repeating depending on the number of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data .= "\t\t<li id=\"".$vNArray['Brandon']."\">".$vNArray['Murphy']."</li>\n";
```

You've hardcoded the vNArray keys, so that regardless of which name got matched, you're always outputting the same values. You'd want

```
$data .= "\t\t<li id=\"{$key}\">{$value}</li>\n";
```

instead.

There's no need to do the string concatenation as you are. PHP can insert array elements into a string nicely, and it eliminates the need to escape quotes everywhere, which means for hideously ugly code to read through.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your loop carefully.

You're using a `foreach` loop, which means you are going through the array each time.

Your `if(in_array(...))` condition checks to see whether the key is in your `$display_id` array. That happens twice, for Brandon and Murphy.

When that condition happens twice, $data is appended twice meaning you will get the results displayed twice.

I'm not sure what this helps, but just look at your loops carefully. Can you clarify what you're exactly trying to achieve, or what your desired output is?

Good luck.

EDIT:

I reread your question and realized something -- do you just want your output to print once?

Look into the `break` syntax. After you append it in the `if` condition, add a `break;` and that will break out of the loop printing it once.

Comment: Thanks for your response Foo, I need to hardcode the ID's because I want specific values in specific placeholders in the code. I tried to target those id's with your syntax but it came up with an error. On your second point, the BREAK; solution seems to be a brilliant one, however when I append it before the else above it just stops right at the first generated line and nothing that appears after it is generated. Any ideas?